# Hack the plot handler to display every x line on a 3D plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

**Edit for the bounty**

I'd like to apply a "graph paper" pattern to 3D graphs.

[image: ![Image1]

**So far**

I "emulate" the graph paper (like) patterns by superposing the same graph with different styles as in these posts [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r2zd.png) and below.

[image]

There must be a smarter way than the superposition of styles that really slows the computations.

Hence my question **How to hack the plot handler on a 3D plot so that we can draw 1 line every x with a different style (larger line width ? other color ? etc) ?**

As a more general case, it could be applied to have a graph paper style pattern on 3d graphs.

**Graph paper in TikZ**

[image]

https://texample.net/tikz/examples/graph-paper/

**NB :** In terms of pedagogy, it enables me to "cut" the graph along the X or Y to illustrate the 3D graph (I still miss by Z but it'll be another question). The graph paper is distorted and it gives a good idea of where is convexity.

=====================================

**Original question**

After [how-to-tranch-a-3d-plot-by-x-or-y](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541894/how-to-tranch-a-3d-plot-by-x-or-y/541932#541932), the more general question that has risen is

**How to hack the plot handler on a 3D plot so that we can draw 1 line every `x` with a different style (larger `line width` ? other `color` ? etc) ?**

The graph below shows the manual tranching along `x` and `y`.

[image]

But how could we actually use the lines already on the 3D plot directly to do that ? (rather than 3 `addplot` superposed)

[image]

Updated MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white!20!orange); color(2.5cm)=(orange!75!red)}}


\newif\ifTwoD
\newif\ifThreeD
\newif\ifTranchX
\newif\ifTranchY

\TwoDtrue
\ThreeDtrue

\TranchXtrue
\TranchYtrue

\pgfplotsset{ 
2DX/.style ={samples y=10,mesh,patch type=line,thick,red}, 
2DY/.style ={samples y=10,mesh,patch type=line,thick,black}, 
3D/.style ={surf,opacity=0.2}, }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
    view={-30}{30},
    axis lines=left,
    axis on top,
    axis line style={black!40},
    xlabel style ={sloped},
    ylabel style ={sloped},
    colormap name=whitered,
    ticklabel style={font=\small},
    samples=51]

\ifTwoD     
\ifTranchX \addplot3[2DX]   (y,x,{exp(-x^2-y^2)}); \fi
\ifTranchY \addplot3[2DY]   {exp(-x^2-y^2)}      ; \fi    
\fi    

\ifThreeD   \addplot3 [surf,opacity=0.2]    {exp(-x^2-y^2)};    \fi

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer but just a comment. It is to say that it might be harder to do what you suggest for a simple reason: the surface plots draw small polygons rather than lines. That is, you can change the line width, but may always change it for twice as many lines as you want. Hacking in the line width is actually not too difficult if you want to spend the `point meta` on that (which means that you cannot use a different point meta for fill colors, say). One only needs a 3d version of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65765), in which `opacity` gets traded for `line width`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white!20!orange); 
color(2.5cm)=(orange!75!red)}}
\pgfplotsset{2DX/.style ={samples y=10,mesh,%patch type=line,thick,red, 
    }, 
2DY/.style ={samples y=10,mesh,patch type=line,thick,black}, 
3D/.style ={surf,
point meta={(abs(x-int(x))<0.02?1:0)+(abs(y-int(y))<0.02?1:0)-%
    (abs(x-int(x))<0.02&&abs(y-int(y))<0.02?1:0)},
faceted color=black,
line width=0.2+0.8*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000
}}
\begin{document}
\def\pgfplotspointmetatransformed{1000}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    view={-30}{30},
    axis lines=left,
    axis on top,
    axis line style={black!40},
    xlabel style ={sloped},
    ylabel style ={sloped},
    %colormap name=whitered,
    ticklabel style={font=\small},
    samples=51]

     \addplot3 [3D]    {exp(-x^2-y^2)};    

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, always two adjacent lines become thick.

This seems to suggest that one may have to really go to some core routines to get the desired results. In other words, you may need to come up with a new plot handler.

Comment: Interesting answer ! I did not expect this rendering but I'm interested in the way it highlights convexity area (I'll need that for other curves). I just tried your code with more samples (101), Tell me if I'm wrong but I lose in readability what I get in precision (a smoother curve) ?

Comment: @JeT If you increase the number of samples, you may want to reduce the overall line width in `line width=0.2+0.8*\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000`, which was chosen to have a very visible effect.

Comment: you're right ! the rendering is actually very interesting ! Did you notice a funny distortion on the very top the graph ?

Comment: @JeT This distortion can be cured by adding `[line join=round,line cap=round]` to the options of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @•TikZling I am working on your code. Very impressed ! I always forget about metapoints :) One last thing, the performance to produce one graph (I have more complex ones) seems to be altered by the calculation of the metapoints right ?

Comment: @JeT Yes, I think so. However, if you compile with lualatex the effect may not be too big. But I did not do any benchmarks.

Comment: Thank you ! Your link (in your non answer :) is very useful too. I'lll try with lualatex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I regret other TeX gurus did not comment on your comments. Maybe your answer is the final answer. A marmot friend of mine advised me to create a question on pgfplot GitHub. I might have an answer there :)

Comment: @JeT Yes, I am very sorry. It would be very useful to have features of the kind you describe...