# Tikz Heatmap size adaption help needed

Tags: pgfplots

I am using the below listed template for Tikz. I would like to adapt the heatmap in a 4x8 manner. But am not succeeding as I do not grasp the coordindex.

Help would be much appreciated :)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image, % We want a square grid, not a rectangular one
    scatter, % This activates the color mapping
    colormap/viridis, % Choose the colormap
    colorbar, % Add a legend
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
    grid=minor, % Grid lines between the intervals
    minor tick num=1, % One minor tick per interval
    tickwidth=0pt, % Don't draw the major tick marks
    y dir=reverse, % Y increases downward
    xticklabel pos=right, % X axis labels go to the top
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5}, % Add half a unit on all sides
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={% A bit of magic for scaling the circles in axis units
      \pgfplotstransformcoordinatex{sqrt(abs(\pgfplotspointmeta))}% Area scales with the square of the radius
      \scope[mark size=\pgfplotsunitxlength*\pgfmathresult/2, fill=mapped color]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
      \endscope%
    }
]
\addplot +[
    point meta=explicit, % We'll provide values for the color and size
    only marks, % No lines between the points
    ] table [
    x expr={int(mod(\coordindex+0.01,5))}, % The position depends on the coordinate index, not the X or Y values
    y expr={int((\coordindex+0.01)/5))},
    meta=value
] {
X   Y   value

0.7 0   0.80
1.5 0   0.80
3.8 0   0.80
9.9 0   0.5
19.7    0   0.08

0.7 1   0.61
1.5 1   0.61
3.8 1   0.64
9.9 1   0.62
19.7    1   0.61

0.7 2   0.53
1.5 2   0.54
3.8 2   0.57
9.9 2   0.53
19.7    2   0.52

0.7 5   0.52
1.5 5   0.52
3.8 5   0.55
9.9 5   0.49
19.7    5   0.49

0.7 10  0.52
1.5 10  0.53
3.8 10  0.56
9.9 10  0.50
19.7    10  0.50
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are arranged in a 4 x n grid by replacing the `5` with a `4` in the following two lines:

```
x expr={int(mod(\coordindex+0.01,4))}, % The position depends on the coordinate index, not the X or Y values
y expr={int((\coordindex+0.01)/4))}
```

The macro `\coordindex` holds the index of the current coordinate. The expression `int(mod(\coordindex+0.01,4))` calculates the remainder of the division of `\coordindex` by `4`, truncated to an integer. The small value of `0.01` is added to avoid issues with precision. The expression results in the following sequence: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3..., which we can use as the x coordinate for the circles.

The expression `int((\coordindex+0.01)/4))` divides the coordinate index by 4, again adding a small value to avoid issues with precision, and truncates the result to an integer, resulting in the following sequence: 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, which we can use as the y coordinate for the circles.

Comment: long time no see! I follow all your answers! (feels like my daughter is writing to Beyonce :p). A marmot friend of mine told me once that you might be the one having an answer to this [long time question for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541934/hack-the-plot-handler-to-display-every-x-line-on-a-3d-plot). This pattern has great results with students but my method of superposition makes it very slow...

Comment: Jake, thanks a lot! I will give a try right away and let you know :-)

Comment: Hi Jake, it worked out! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Jake would it be possible to also adapt the size of the circles to a different scale? i.e. I would like to use this in order to represent raw data instead of correlations. So instead of a range of 1 to 0 I would like to represent number in a range of 200 to 600 with proportionate circles and colours from the legend (also 200 to 600). thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Jake :-) kind reminder :-) thanks you!

Comment: @Jake :-) still looking for help on this :-)

Comment: @poebelchen: You can use `point meta min=200, point meta max=600` to adjust the colorbar, and `scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/100}` to scale the circles (adjust the `100` to resize the circles). In general, it's best to open a new question for follow-up issues like this.

Comment: thanks you so much :)